# How to check if Request_URI is nested

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to set the title for my pages to be dynamic by using Blade if statements. Currently I have it working properly for urls such as "domain.com/home" and using an else to handle the root "domain.com/".

The question I have is how to check if the url will be nested such as "domain.com/profile/settings". I'm wanting pages like this to be displayed in various ways, such as the above example displaying like "Settings | Profile" as the title.

Here is the code I have currently.

```
<title>
    @if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] != "/")
        {{ ucfirst(preg_replace('{/}', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) }}
    @else
        Home
    @endif
</title>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the string **$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]**. First you need to split into an array

```
<title>
    @if($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] != "/")
        <?php $dataTitles = [];
              $dataTitles = explode ("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
              if (count($dataTitles) > 1) {
                   unset($dataTitles[0]);
              } 

              echo implode('|', $dataTitles);
         ?>
    @else
        Home
    @endif
</title>
```

Comment: Thanks, might need to make some minor adjustments with certain pages, but this helped.

What would happen if I was to be on a page such as "domain.com/one/two/three/four"? I'm guessing since it unsets only the first array item it will display "two | three | four"?

Comment: @Kankuro domain.com/one/two/three/four when I transfer to an array, I am dropping the first element of this domain.com and will be one|two|three|four